# 3.5mm PCIe Headset sound card I.e.same as laptop - not seperate mic socket

Tags: desktop-computer, pci-express, sound-card, headset, 3.5mm

I recently built a few new PC's for our home and buying budget motherboards I was surprised I couldn't find any with headset output either for front panel or rear panel connections (its been 5 years or so since I built the last batch of family/gaming PC's).

So I decided I would simply build the PC's and find a PCIe headset soundcard later and fit to rear panel. Now its 'later' and 'simply' seems not an option as all the sound cards I can find seem to be 5.1 and 7.1 with separate microphone.

I am not interested in a splitter lead or any USB dongle suggestions/options.

Does the PCIe card I am after have a particular name so I can search directly and can anyone link me to a suitable product?

Comment: I think you've found a hole in the market. USB dongles can be got on eBay for about £$€ 4

Comment: Can you even buy old school headsets with separate microphone anymore?????

Comment: I've no idea,sorry. I'm actually a professional sound engineer & have never needed headphones with a built-I'm mic ;))